# Power BI Desktop - Home Menu - Insert - does not have the Image tile

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am completely new to Power BI Desktop and am following a tutorial to create a report. This involves adding an image. However my version (2.83.5894.961 64-bit (July 2020)) does not have the Image tile on the Home menu in the Insert group. How do I add this tile please?

My menu ribon:

[image]

Tutorial menu ribon:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Insert menu and check "Image".